# Why isn't my TimeSpan.Add() working?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

There has to be an easy answer:

```
var totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

foreach (var timesheet in timeSheets)
{
   //assume "time" is a correct, positive TimeSpan
   var time = timesheet.EndTime - timesheet.StartTime;
   totalTime.Add(time);
}
```

There's only one value in the list `timeSheets` and it is a positive `TimeSpan` (verified on local inspection).

Comment: For a different approach, you can accomplish all that with this: `var totalTime = timeSheets.Sum(sheet => sheet.EndTime - sheet.StartTime);`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

TimeSpans are value types.
Try:

`totalTime = totalTime.Add(time)`

Answer (score 28):

This is a common mistake. `TimeSpan.Add` returns a new instance of `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 7):

```
totalTime = totalTime.Add(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpans are value types and can use the += operator similar to integral and floating point numeric types. I find the += operator neat to use in this situation which is the same as writing `x = x + y`.

```
var totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

foreach (var timesheet in timeSheets)
{
   totalTime += (timesheet.EndTime - timesheet.StartTime);
}
```